# What are the four last numbers in the series $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 +\cdots+3458^{3458}$?

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

> What are the four last numbers in $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 +\cdots+3458^{3458}$

Hello, I have come across this question, and I have no idea how to solve it. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the obvious pattern holds, the last number is $3458^{3458}$, the one before that is $3457^{3457}$, then $3456^{3456}$ and then $3455^{3455}$.

Comment: Maybe he meant last digits in the sum of series. Last four terms seems too trivial.:o

Comment: @Mann Maybe.  Perhaps some clarification will be posted.  But it could well be an exercise in recognising what is meant by $\cdots$ in an expression.

Comment: Hehe...good one! The OP deserves this for asking in the way (s)he did.

Comment: @Timbuc My answer was not intended as a joke, I really think this might be what the OP wants.  (But possibly not...)

Comment: @David If the OP really meant it that way, then this is one of the most increidibly trivial question I've ever seen here. But perhaps you're right...

Comment: @Timbuc OK, probably "trivial" is a fair description, but as an experienced university teacher, I can assure you that I've seen significant numbers of students having initial difficulties with "dots" expressions.